# После создания новой модели, предыдущая не может быть найдена

Tags: laravel

У меня был рабочий код, я решил создать новую модель `Comment` и миграцию. Я выполнил 2 команды в командной строке, `php artisan make:model Comment` - создал модель и `php artisan make:migration create_comments_table` - создал новую миграцию, после этого выполнил ещё одну команду - `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, чтобы база данных обновилась.
Модель `Comment` выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'spot_id'
    ];

    public function spot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Spot');
    }
}
```

Миграция выглядит так:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('spot_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('spot_id')->references('id')->on('spots');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

Также в модель `Spot`, которая у меня уже была, я добавил метод `comments` и теперь модель выглядит так:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Spot extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'lat', 'lng', 'description', 'user_id'
    ];

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video');
    }

    public function tricks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Trick')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

После этих действий любая страница где используется модель `Spot` перестала работать, ошибка отлавливается в любом контроллере где используется модель `Spot`, сама ошибка `Class 'App\Spot' not found`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После отката миграции, удалении метода `comments` из модели `Spot` и удалении модели `Comment` появляется другая ошибка- `include(D:\Install\XAMPP\htdocs\parkour\vendor\composer/../../app/Comment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, помогла команда `composer dump-autoload`. Буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит мне почему произошла такая ошибка и пришлось использовать эту команду, до этого модели и миграции нормально и без этой команды работали. И что за команда `php artisan clear-compiled`, она заменяет вышеуказанную?